# PL SQL Function - How to call

Tags: sql, function, parameters, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a function in PL/SQL as follows (being used in Oracle APEX):

```
create or replace FUNCTION User_Levels(result OUT VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

v_user_types employee.user_type%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT user_type
INTO v_user_types
FROM Employee
WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');
IF v_user_types = 1
THEN
result := 'TRUE';
ELSE
result := 'FALSE';
END IF; 
END User_Levels;​
```

How can I call this just to see its current output in normal SQL i.e. does it evaluate to True or False at the time it is run.

Do I really need the OUT parameter called result?

Answer (score 1):

From SQL*Plus:

```
var result varchar2(10);
var rc varchar2(10);

exec :rc := user_levels(:result);

print rc
print result
```

However, your function is invalid because you have no `return` clause. Since the only thing you can return is `result`, having that as both an out parameter and the return value is redundant. Which you keep depends on how you want to use it, but I'd suggest a function is more flexible and appropriate here.

```
create or replace FUNCTION User_Levels
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_user_types employee.user_type%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT user_type
    INTO v_user_types
    FROM Employee
    WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');

    IF v_user_types = 1 THEN
        RETURN 'TRUE';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'FALSE';
    END IF;
END User_Levels;​
/
```

... assuming `v('APP_USER')` does something sensible. You can then just do:

```
select user_levels from dual;
```

Comment: This code wouldn't work without creating APEX session, because v('APP_USER') work only in APEX session. If you want run this code from SQL*PLUS, search in google for "Create APEX session" - this will return you many samples of procedure creating APEX session. Run this procedure before this code, and it will work.

Comment: @NoGotnu - thanks, I wondered if `v()` was an APEX thing, I haven't used it. You could maybe fake it with a dummy `v()` function that just returns `USER`, but better if there are already tools to do it cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Should work.  Typically, you would create a variable (like v_user_types) and return that (p_result).  Also, you need to make sure that your v('APP_USER') is also uppercase.

Additionally, you can not run this from a SQL*PLUS or any command prompt as v('APP_USER') is application variable; therefore, you have to test this on an APEX page.

```
create or replace FUNCTION User_Levels(p_result OUT VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

v_user_types employee.user_type%TYPE;
p_result VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
    SELECT user_type
    INTO v_user_types
    FROM Employee
    WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');

    IF (v_user_types = 1) THEN
       p_result := 'TRUE';
    ELSE
       p_result := 'FALSE';
    END IF; 

 RETURN p_result;

END User_Levels;​
```